# Why does a string instrument get out of tune when a string breaks?

Tags: strings

Usually, when a string breaks on my guitar/bass, the remaining strings get out tune. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the tension changed and the neck might bend a little back, causing the remaining strings to get out of tune (I suppose you notice the pitch a bit higher)

Comment: And if your guitar has a floating bridge the problem is exacerbated as the lowered tension on the bridge means the other strings get raised in pitch, in some cases by quite a large amount